# How Can I get the Data and Flashmessage in Form by redirecting to a function in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I want to display the success message and the Product size in Product page..
this is possible if pass the data in view, but not displaying by redirecting the function... here is my **controller code**

```
class Addcontroller extends MY_Controller{
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
      $this->load->model('vendor/Addmodel', 'add', TRUE);
      $this->load->model('vendor/Showmodel', 'show', TRUE);
}


  function add_product(){

   if($this->add->add_product($post)==TRUE){

        $this->db->close();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Product has been added 
       successfully');
        return redirect('product');


    }
    function product(){

    $data['product_size'] = $this->show->show_product_size();
    $this->load->view('product',$data);

      }

     }
  }
```

Comment: you mean to say that you want to access the flashdata in a method inside controller itself?

Comment: yes flashdata.......
and  this
 $data['product_size'] = $this->show->show_product_size();

Comment: see in my product function through which i am accessing my view, where i m passing no data parameter...............

Comment: based on whatever ive understood ive posted my code.

Comment: Thank you very much but not working.... it is working only, IF I load view in add_product function {$data['product_size'] = $this->show->show_product_size();
    $this->load->view('product',$data);
} instead of redirecting to function,

Comment: I thinking it is being expired to reach till the View

Comment: Basically when you load view the page gets redirected to your view and the function which invokes view  becomes a part of the URL. To avoid the conflict redirect is used mostly.

Answer (score 1):

add this to your constructor method:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

set flashdata in the controller method:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('item', 'value');
```

Retrieve in your view:

```
if(!empty($this->session->flashdata('item'))){
$flash=$this->session->flashdata('item');
//do whatever you want.
}
```

Hope this helps.